# How can my module inform the drupal Block module that a block no longer exists?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

My module defines a variable number of blocks, which are then made available to the "block" module for display is specific regions.

When my module deletes a block, drupal still thinks it exists. How can I tell drupal that a block should be discarded? I'm looking for something like block_delete($module, $delta), but that does not exist.

Cheers,

Albert.

Comment: You don't have to. If hook_block() is called somewhere in your module, a block is added. What you mean by "When my module deletes a block" exactly ? Does it create a "custom block" in the same way as you add custom blocks at /admin/build/block/add ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Here is a more concrete example: (1) user goes to my module's admin page and can add/edit/delete any number of "blocks". These are then made visible to the block module via hook_block(). (2) user then puts one of these blocks (delta 1, say), in a given region. (3) user goes back to the admin page and deletes block delta 1 (4) now visiting any page gives me an error because the block system "thinks" that block delta 1 of my module is still in a region, but it no longer exists. So: when deleting my block, how to force the block module to delete it from all regions?

Answer (score 1):

You can search the block table for any references for your block and remove them from the table in the submit function of the form you are using to delete the block. I don't think there is a cleaner way to insure that the block is removed. You might review how menu_block handles this (if it doesn't).